# GetDeviceCaps return different values than screen resolution

Tags: c, winapi, screen, resolution

I'm trying to get the resolution of my screen, as it appears in desktop -> graphic properties -> display, on my windows 10 computer. the value there is 1920X1080.

However, when I use the following code to get this value:

```
HDC hScreenDC = CreateDC(L"DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL);
int width = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, HORZRES);
int height = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, VERTRES);
```

I get 1280X720.

I get the same values using GetDpiForMonitor and GetSystemMetrics functions too.
Can someone explain me this difference between the values?
Thank you.

Comment: You did not declare your program to be `<dpiAware>`.  So DPI virtualization pretends that your monitor does not run at 150% but still has the legacy 100% (aka 96 dpi) value.  Modify the manifest or call SetProcessDPIAware() as [noted here](http://blog.xojo.com/2013/11/18/writing_high-dpi_aware_windows_apps/).